# Binding a Dictionary to a repeater asp.net 4

Tags: asp.net, dictionary, repeater

i have a dictionary in this form Dictionary<int, List<CartItem>>, this dictionany contain informationa about my shopping cart item. i am looking for a way to display the result in a repeater or a datalist what ever is better. i have started using a repeater and i got stuck

i want to display the information in the list in the repeater for each element in the repeater

in the page.aspx.cs

```
void bindinfo()
{
        ShoppingCart cart = ShoppingCart.GetShoppingCart();
        RepeaterCustomerShoppingCarts.DataSource = cart.dictionaryShoppingCart;
        RepeaterCustomerShoppingCarts.DataBind();
}
```

in page.aspx

```
<asp:Repeater id="RepeaterCustomerShoppingCarts" onitemdatabound="RepeaterCustomerShoppingCarts_ItemDataBound" runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                 <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="shopping-table">
                    <tr>
                        <th>&nbsp;</th>
                        <th>Merchant Name</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                        <th>Total Amount</th>
                        <th>&nbsp;</th>
                    </tr>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
               <tr>

                <td class="first"><asp:Image ID="MerchantLogo" runat="server" width="52" height="46"/></td>
                <td>
                    <b><asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></b>
                    <p> <asp:Label ID="lblDetails" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label> </p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="dropdown">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblQuantity" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td><b><asp:Label ID="lblTotalPrice" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label> </b></td>
                <td><asp:HyperLink ID="hlShopDetails" CssClass="remove" runat="server">More Details</asp:HyperLink></td>
            </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                </table>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

any help and advice to try to display the information would be great. the purpose of the page is u can have many shopping cart depending on different merchant and u display them here than there is a link called more details it will take you to a specific cart.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
protected void RepeaterCustomerShoppingCarts_ItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ItemType.Item){
         // Grab all your controls like this
         var lblQuantity = e.Item.FindControl("lblQuantity") as Label;
         var NestedRepeater = e.Item.FindControl("NestedRepeater") as Repeater;
         // Get the current data
         var data = (KeyValuePair<Int32, List<CartItem>>)e.Item.DataItem;
         //Bind the values
         lblQuantity.Text = data.Value.Count.ToString();
         NestedRepeater.DataSource = data.Value;
         NestedRepeater.DataBind();
    }
}
```

The markup would look something like this.

```
<asp:Repeater id="RepeaterCustomerShoppingCarts" onitemdatabound="RepeaterCustomerShoppingCarts_ItemDataBound" runat="server">     
        <ItemTemplate>     
            <asp:Label id="lblQuantity" runat="server" />
            <asp:Repeater runat="server" id="NestedRepeater">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <!-- whatever your controls -->
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The thing here is that you control your layout in the code behind. Grab the necessary controls there and the current data. Then just do your bindings as normally.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using the normal Eval("ColumnName") on a dictionary you would simply do Eval("value")

You could do something like this.

```
<asp:Label ID="lblQuantity" runat="server" Text='<%#(Eval("key")=="Quantity" ? Eval("value") : "") %>' />
```

Comment: basically you check the dictionary for the key, and if the key matches the key for the label, you print out the "value" using Eval()

Comment: i tried different ways to check the key but i could not make it work

Comment: i want to display the information in the list in the repeater for each element in the repeater